# netty udp, bind and send to other addresses

Tags: netty

I need to be able to bind and listen to a port and also be able to send packets to other addresses, is it possible to do this using the already created `DatagramChannelFactory` or `ConnectionlessBootstrap`? Seeing as UDP is connectionless.

```
public static void start() {
DatagramChannelFactory f = new NioDatagramChannelFactory(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
ConnectionlessBootstrap b = new ConnectionlessBootstrap(f);
b.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {

        @Override
    public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
    return Channels.pipeline(new Encoder(), new Decoder(), new ServerHandler());
    }       
        });
    b.bind(new InetSocketAddress(Config.PORT));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.  Actually, it's always a good idea to reuse a `ChannelFactory`.  `Bootstrap`s are not required to be reused though.  Think of it as a template object in Spring Framework.